# Wrong abbreviation expansion

Tags: abbreviations

I have these abbreviations in my `.vimrc`:

```
iab seq sequent
iab seqs sequents
```

`seqs` expands to

```
sequents
i seq sequent
```

in a tex file (I have installed vim-latex).
In an empty buffer `seqs` expands correctly to
`sequents`. How could I get the correct expansion in a tex file?

**EDIT:**

I addition, abbreviations are not expanding at all in a line of a tex buffer, if, e. g., left movements of cursor were made in that line.

I've noticed that all abbreviations work correct in a .tex buffer if triggered with <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>CR</kbd>. One simple way out is

```
imap <f2> <Tab><BS> 
" One space after <BS> in f2
imap <f3> <Tab><BS>
```

and trigger abbreviations with <kbd>f2</kbd> or <kbd>f3</kbd>. Please let me know if you find ` better solution.

Comment: Not sure if this is enough... but maybe try using [`:inoreabbrev`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:inoreabbrev) instead? It doesn't do recursive expansions of the rhs, which is what might be triggering unwanted behavior when combined with vim-latex...

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger want to write an answer?

Comment: I think we're still missing one piece, which is what in vim-latex is causing the abbreviation to misbehave... I'll see if I can reproduce that somewhere and debug a bit more...

Comment: `inoreabbrev` works in the same way as `iab` in my example: `seqs` expands to the same text. The Abolish plugin adds an additional asterisk. `seq` expands to `* sequent` in a tex buffer (and I even didn't try `seqs`). I think that vim-latex is buggy for abbreviations

Comment: Sorry, `inoreabbrev` also adds the additional asterisk. So the additional Abolish asterisk comes from `inoreabbrev`, I think

Comment: Try following the steps in [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51)

Comment: imap
has the line i <Space> * <C-R>=<SNR>16_LookupCharacter(" ")<CR>
But punctuation characters also trigger the same wrong expansion of abbs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a bug of vim-latex v1.9.0 that is fixed in v1.10.0.

I finally managed to reproduce the issue you reported and after using [git bisect](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#_binary_search) on the [vim-latex sources](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex), I managed to narrow it down to [commit ba140b1bd2d8](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/commit/ba140b1bd2d8c77e2818772a10338cce72f789d4) which fixes this issue.

(I didn't see a bug report or a pull request for that commit, so not really sure whether it was meant to fix a bug, or just using a better API and ended up fixing the bug as a side effect.)

My suggestion is that you should upgrade to [v1.10.0](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/releases/tag/v1.10.0), but applying that patch to v1.9.0 seems to work as well (if for some reason you prefer to cherry-pick a single fix.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I cannot install vim-latex v1.10.0. Fedora's dnf has only v1.9.0. When I do
dnf remove vim-latex
and manually extract v1.10.0 in ~/.vim,
(according to http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download then vim doesn't read files in the extracted directory ~/.vim/vim-latex-1.10.0
Latex-suite commands are not working and :scriptnames doesn't list the files in the directory ? How could I get vim read the directory when launched?

Comment: @Romas You can find vim-latex 1.10.0 for Fedora 29 [here](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1135113), download the `vim-latex-1.10.0-1.fc29.noarch.rpm` file from there and install it on your system with dnf or `rpm -Uvh vim-latex-*.rpm`. That might be the simplest approach.

Comment: @Romas The reason why your unpacking into `~/.vim` didn't work is that you're not expected to have a `vim-latex-1.10.0` directory there, but instead you're expected to have the *contents* of that directory there, so you'll have `~/.vim/plugin/...`, `~/.vim/ftplugin/...`, etc. That, of course, is a problem if you already have a `~/.vim` with stuff in it... You *could* merge the contents, but that's too much hassle... A better approach is to use a plug-in manager, such as [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), in which case you can load it with `Plug 'vim-latex/vim-latex'`.

Comment: @Romas If this indeed fixes the issue you reported, please mark this answer as such (by clicking the check mark on it.) I see you reported a follow up problem, I'll take a look at it now. Cheers! Filipe