# vim-latex: sometimes abbreviations do not expand in tex buffers

Tags: plugin-vim-latex, abbreviations

I have installed vim-latex v1.10.0 on Fedora 28, using vim-plug:

```
Plug 'vim-latex/vim-latex'
```

I've defined an insert mode abbreviation:

```
:iab bd text
```

I can trigger `bd` to expand to "text" only with <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>CR</kbd> in a line of the type:

```
rrrrr bd tttttt
```

in a tex buffer. Neither <kbd>Space</kbd> nor punctuation characters work (but they work in an empty buffer). Why?

Comment: While I'm not sure about it, It's likely a consequence of `IMAP` plugin that vim-latex uses to define all its insert-mode expansions. The plugin is quite intrusive and have a tendency to neutralize the usual way to define abbreviations and insert-mode mappings. When vim-latex is present, in (La)TeX buffers, it's better to rely on IMAP to define your own expansions, in a ftplugin.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but think this is the same issue as [Wrong abbreviation expansion](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17265/wrong-abbreviation-expansion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in vim-latex.

I filed [Issue #141](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/issues/141) at GitHub to report the issue, and prepared [PR #142](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/pull/142) with a possible fix.

---

**UPDATE**: The PR has been accepted upstream, so you might be able to get it fixed by updating your local plug-in, with a command such as:

```
:PlugUpdate
```

(And you might need to restart vim afterwards.)

It would be nice if you could confirm this does indeed fix your issue.

Comment: Plug 'filbranden/vim-latex' answered my question. Abbreviations are expanding correctly know. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good to know @Romas! Please upvote and mark my answer as correct, as it might help others who are going through the same issues and bump into this page... See ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more details. Glad your problem is solved now! :-)

Comment: BTW, you can go back to the official `Plug 'vim-latex/vim-latex'`, since the change I had was accepted upstream too... (I recommend you do that, since I might not keep that repo around for much longer, and pointing at the official one means you'll get updates later on.)

Comment: I confirm that Plug 'vim-latex/vim-latex' also gives the correct expansion of abbreviations now. I am allowed "only post 1 time each day due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from my network" ? I voted for your answers to both my questions, but get a message that "votes of less 15 reputation are recorded but not publicly displayed". I cannot tick your answers because I do not see the "check mark beside the answer" on my screen (tried firefox and chrome). (I could see the green ticks beside answers in other people's questions, but see just background on that spot in my questions.)

Comment: `only post 1 time each day due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from my network` That is because you keep posting "answers" that are not answers @A.Romas, which then have to be deleted :-) You should *only* use answers for full answers. For everything else, use comments, which is what this is!

Comment: @A.Romas Also, it seems you're using two accounts... You asked the question with "Romas", so you'll be able to accept the answers (here and the other question) with that account... I recommend you [take the tour](https://vi.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site. Also try to answer some questions on the site, so you can get a bit more reputation to use comments. (It doesn't take a lot.) Good luck!